# Using Jison to create / translate simple script to another language

Tags: javascript, parsing, jison

Have been playing with Jison to try to create an "interpreter" for a very simple scripting syntax (this is just for a personal messing around project, no business case!)

It's been about 20 years since I had to create a compiler, and I think I'm just not grasping some of the concepts.

What I am thinking of doing is give a program of very simple statements, one per line, to Jison, and get a stream of Javascript statements back that then perform the actions.

I may be looking at this wrong - maybe I need to actually perform the actions during the parse? This doesn't sound right though.

Anyway, what I've got is (I'm trying this online btw http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/)

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%options case-insensitive
%%

\s+                        /* skip whitespace */
is\s+a\b                   return 'OCREATE'
is\s+some\b                return 'ACREATE'
[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9]*\b  return 'IDENTIFIER'
<<EOF>>                    return 'EOF'

/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */

%start input

%% /* language grammar */

input
        : /* empty */
        | program EOF
        { return $1; }
;

program
        : expression 
                { $$ = $1; }
        | program expression
                { $$ = $1; }
        ;

expression
        : IDENTIFIER OCREATE IDENTIFIER
            { $$ = 'controller.createOne(\'' + $1 + '\', \'' + $3 + '\');' }

        | IDENTIFIER ACREATE IDENTIFIER
            { $$ = 'controller.createSeveral(\'' + $1 + '\', \'' + $3 + '\');' }
;
```

So, for the input:

```
basket is some apples
orange is a fruit
```

...I want:

```
controller.createSeveral('basket', 'apples');
controller.createOne('orange', 'fruit');
```

What I am getting is:

```
controller.createSeveral('basket', 'apples');
```

This kind of makes sense to me to get a single result, but I have no idea what to do to progress with building my output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your second production for `program`:

```
program
    : expression
            { $$ = $1; }
    | program expression
            { $$ = $1; }
```

What the second production is saying, basically, is "a program can be a (shorter) program followed by an expression, but its semantic value is the value of the shorter program."

You evidently want the value of the program to be *augmented* by the value of the expression, so you need to say that:

```
program
    : expression
            { $$ = $1; }
    | program expression
            { $$ = $1.concat($2); }
```

(or `$$ = $1 + $2` if you prefer. And you might want a newline for readability.)

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I was looking for. Very clear explanation, thankyou!